# C#/Json.Net Exceptions slowing down parsing

Tags: c#, json, parsing, try-catch, json.net

I use Newtonsoft.Json to parse a json string.

The data i`m parsing contains a lot of entrys which a huge load of 
attributes several of them are optional.

The Code for the parsing looks like this:

```
public bool Parse(string JSONString)
    {
        JObject o;

        try
        {
            jResponse = JObject.Parse(JSONString);
        }
        catch (JsonReaderException)
        {
            return false;
        }


        foreach (JObject jResult in jResponse[ParserConstants.ResultsTag])
        {

            MyObject myObject = new MyObject();

            try
            {
                myObject.Title = (string)jResult[ParserConstants.TitleTag];
            }
            catch
            {
                myObject.Title = String.Empty;
            }

            // This goes on for like 15 other elements
            // Some have a continue in catch, thats when the attribute is mandatory
            // Some have a deeper Structure like jResult[Tag1][Tag2][0][Tag3]

            Results.Add(c);
        }
        return (Results != null && Results.Count > 0);
    }
```

All of this works fine but the parsing is very slow because a lot of exceptions coming up on fields that have no value. ( Thats what i guess ) There like 1200 Exceptions when parsing all the data.

The Exceptions are the following:

**A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.DLL**

I tryed something like this instead of the try catch:

```
if( jResult[TitleTag] != null && jResult[TitleTag].HasValues ){
    myObject.Title = (string) jResult[TitleTag];
} else {
    myObject.Title = String.Empty;
}
```

Unfortunaly it didnt worked out and the Data couldnt be parsed properly.

Could somebody help me out with an alternative to the try-catch approach avoiding the exceptions?

I´d be glad!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JObject` works as `IDictionary<string, JToken>` so there's a `TryGetValue` method on it:

```
JToken token;
if (jResult.TryGetValue(TitleTag, out token)) {
    myObject.Title = (string)token;
} else {
    myObject.Title = String.Empty;
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much works fine so far! Do you happen to have an idea how i can handle a deeper structure like -> jResult[Tag1][Tag2][0][Tag3]?

Comment: I think you can try to define some extension methods as helpers so you can write code like `jResult.TryGet(Tag1).TryGet(Tag2)...`. The extension methods can accept `null` as `this` so it's easy to handle the case that doesn't has the value you want.